# How to force Dolphin to not execute executable files

Tags: settings, executable, dolphin

Dolphin has a nasty habit to execute whatever executable file I accidentally click on. How to turn off this behavior? Is there anything like in Nautilus which would allow to select appropriate action?

Answer (score 3):

There is no real gui option in `Dolphin` that allows you to do what you want, but I think the way to do this would be to edit the list of `mime types`, as has been suggested by 'Farry' on the [KDE forums](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=52818#p211583). I have just tested the method below quoted from the KDE forums and it **did** work for me. Make sure to update the `mime database` as in the instructions and quit `Dolphin` and reload it to see the difference (restart if necessary).

Quoted from [the KDE forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=52818#p211583), (with my `gksudo gedit` addition) credit to 'Farry':

(Make a backup of the file before you proceed)

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
and find the line that starts the shellscript section:
  <mime-type type="application/x-shellscript">
then scroll down to find this line within that section:
   <sub-class-of type="application/x-executable"/>
then comment it out like so:
   <!-- <sub-class-of type="application/x-executable"/> -->
save that, then compile it with this command:
  sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

As I said, it worked for me and it should for anyone, as long as you use `gedit's`  search capability to find the right part of the file to edit; be **careful** as it is an important file. As I mentioned earlier, it is important to make a backup of it before editing it.

In the future, if you want to return to the original state of the file and let scripts execute when clicking on them, the commenting out as discussed above can be removed and the `mime database` updated again.

Comment: Is there any way to do that for a user, not in the global file? I.e. without any root access?